# How to delete an item in a reverse sorted array in *ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to delete a specific item in the array based on the `index`. Currently, I have an issue deleting the first and last element of the array. When I try delete the last element, the first element gets deleted and vice versa.

Here's an excerpt from my code

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsList.slice().reverse(); index as i">
  <ion-item>{{item.name}} <button (click)="deleteItem(i)">Delete</button></ion-item>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
itemsList = [{
  name: 'Item 0'
}];
count = 0;

constructor() {}

addItem() {
  this.count += 1
  this.itemsList.unshift({
    name: `Item ${this.count}`
  })
}

deleteItem(index) {
  console.log('Delete ', this.itemsList[index].name)
  this.itemsList.splice(index, 1)
}
```

I created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-psnsjg?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) using StackBlitz. Could anyone please help?

Comment: The index is the index of the item in the *reversed* array. So the code is behaving as expected. Why not pass the item instance in instead and use it to remove it from the array?

Comment: Sure, let me that try way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `length - index - 1` in your splice to get the correct index of the normal array.

```
this.itemsList.splice(this.itemsList.length - index -1, 1)
```

Comment: Awesome, that was it. 

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't code it like this:

```
(click)="deleteItem(item)"
```

It's really a much better way to write code.